# White edge at the bottom of JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I'm working with Javax swing and can't get rid of this tiny white border at the bottom of the JFrame. The way my JFrame is structured is that I have added a bunch of components to a JPanel (ex. buttons, textfields, labels), which then added to the frame. I've tried setting the panel's preferred size to the desired dimensions, then calling pack() on the JFrame but to no avail. Thank you in advance.

[image: White border at the bottom of Frame]

```
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;

public class SampleGUI {
    JFrame frame;
    JPanel panel;
    JLabel label;
    JTextField field;

    public SampleGUI()
    {
        this.frame = new JFrame();
        this.panel = new JPanel();
        this.label = new JLabel("test");
        this.field = new JTextField(20);

        panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 250));
        panel.setLayout(null);

        label.setBounds(50, 75, 80, 25);
        label.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        panel.add(label);

        field.setBounds(120, 80, 80, 20);
        panel.add(field);

        //Background Config
        try
        {
            URL url = new URL("https://watchandlearn.scholastic.com/content/dam/classroom-magazines/watchandlearn/videos/earth-and-space/earth-science-and-space/what-s-in-the-night-sky/english/wall-2018-whatsinthenightskymp4.transform/content-tile-large/image.png");
            BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(url);
            JLabel img = new JLabel();
            img.setSize(500, 250);
            img.setIcon(new ImageIcon(image));
            img.setOpaque(false);
            panel.add(img);
        }
        catch(IOException ignored){}

        frame.setSize(500, 250);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(panel);

        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SampleGUI sample = new SampleGUI();
    }
}
```

Comment: What operating system and version of Java are you using?  I just created a [Swing application on Windows 10 using Java 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67346181/processing-randomized-building-drawing-window-issue/67357167#67357167)  to draw a downtown scene, and I have no white border at the bottom.  Please post a [mre] so we can see how you're creating the JFrame and JPanel.

Comment: Did you set the window to "none resizable" (for [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53982242/weird-white-border-at-bottom-of-jpanel/53982409#53982409)?  You know what - would be easier do diagnose with a [mcve]

Comment: Hello, I apologize. After testing for a while more, I found that JFrame.pack() did remove the white line at the bottom of the frame, however, it did not maintain the desired dimensions specified by the JPanel, so I'm not able to do setResizable(false) because it shrinks the frame drastically. I updated the post to show the code. How can I maintain the dimensions while doing pack()? Thank you for replying.

Comment: @TszhimChan *How can I maintain the dimensions while doing pack()?* - The last statement in your constructor must be: pack(), setVisible( true ). This means: 1) all the components have been added to the frame and 2) the setResizable(...) statement has been invoked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the GUI I put together.  I went ahead and added the other Swing components.  As you can see, there's no line at the bottom.

[image: Starry Night]

I started the Swing application with a call to the `SwingUtilities` `invokeLater` method.  This method ensures that the Swing components are created and executed on the [Event Dispatch Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html).

I created a drawing `JPanel` so I could draw the image on the `JPanel`.  I made the `JPanel` the size of the image.  I used a `GridBagLayout` to lay out the components of the `JPanel`.  The `GridBagLayout` will put the Swing components in columns, and center the group of components.

The `JFrame` method calls have to be called in a specific order.  This is the order I use for my Swing applications.

Here's the complete runnable code.  I made the additional class an inner class so I could post this code as one block.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.net.URL;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class StarryNightGUI implements Runnable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new StarryNightGUI());
    }
    
    private BufferedImage image;
    
    private final BackgroundPanel backgroundPanel;
    
    public StarryNightGUI() {
        try {
            URL url = new URL("https://watchandlearn.scholastic.com/content/dam/"
                + "classroom-magazines/watchandlearn/videos/earth-and-space/"
                + "earth-science-and-space/what-s-in-the-night-sky/english/"
                + "wall-2018-whatsinthenightskymp4.transform/"
                + "content-tile-large/image.png");
            this.image = ImageIO.read(url);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            this.image = null;
        }
        
         this.backgroundPanel = new BackgroundPanel();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Starry Night");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        
        frame.add(backgroundPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    
    public class BackgroundPanel extends JPanel {
        
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        public BackgroundPanel() {
            this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(image.getWidth(), 
                    image.getHeight()));
            this.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
            gbc.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
            
            gbc.gridwidth = 2;
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            String s = "Good Morning: " + LocalDateTime.now().format(
                    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("d MMM yyyy  H:mm a"));
            JLabel label = new JLabel(s);
            label.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
            add(label, gbc);
            
            gbc.gridwidth = 1;
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy++;
            label = new JLabel("Username:");
            label.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
            add(label, gbc);
            
            gbc.gridx++;
            JTextField field = new JTextField(10);
            add(field, gbc);
            
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy++;
            label = new JLabel("Password:");
            label.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
            add(label, gbc);
            
            gbc.gridx++;
            JPasswordField passwordField = new JPasswordField(10);
            add(passwordField, gbc);
            
            gbc.gridwidth = 2;
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy++;
            
            JButton button = new JButton("Login");
            add(button, gbc);
        }
        
        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);
        }
        
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to make you code working replace `frame.add(panel);` with `frame.setContentPane(panel);` and move it just before frame pack

```
    frame.setContentPane(panel);
    frame.pack();
```

Also remove `frame.setSize(...)` since the pack method will take care of the size.

But, in general I would recommend to have a deep look to Gilber's answer, so you can learn a lot about laying out elements in a panel.

[image]